# Conditional Standard Deviation in Ms. Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

So I want to count a standard deviation. I have two columns. The range of the first column is A2:A201. And this column have several labels, one of it is "Good" label. And the range of the second column is E2:E201, this column contains numerous values.

So how to count the standard deviation of the second column when the condition of the first column is "Good"?
And I thought this would work but it's not.

`=STDEV.P(IF($A$2:$A$201="Good",$E$2:$E$201))`

Comment: Hey, just for future reference, use the `{ }` button for code, instead of `>` blockquote. Thank you! :)

Comment: I think all you have to do is confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: @JvdV I use it but I got this error #NAME?

Comment: I found it! I'm using Ms. Excel 2007 so maybe that's why those formula didn't work. This one works though =STDEV(IF($A$2:$A$201="Bullying";$E$2:$E$201))

Comment: Does it really? I find it strange that your `IF` formula doesn't return error when it doesn't have a "false" condition declared. :o

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you calculating it with standard formula (Ctrl+shift+enter):
={SQRT(SUMSQ(B1:B4*(A1:A4="x"))/COUNTIFS(A1:A4;"x")-AVERAGEIFS(B1:B4;A1:A4;"x")^2)}

Another way is to add column with additional calculations.

Similar things work with sumproduct function for example (more information here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/)

**Update**: checked your formula in comment {=STDEV.P(IF(A1:A4="x";B1:B4))}, surprisingly it works))

Comment: @pnuts I guess the alternative formula doesn't work in excel 2007 as well because of sumsq function?)